# web essentials 2012 custom directory for less build folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

does anybody know if is possible in web essentials 2012 to create a custom directory for the build folder of less files? 
The only option I have there is:

```
compile to css folder: true/false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can try `koala` to get everything straightened up.

Here is the [link](http://koala-app.com/).

This [documentation](https://github.com/oklai/koala/wiki/Using-project-settings) shows how to change the output path.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible in Web Essentials 2013, by modifying the Web Essentials JSON config:

```
  "Less": {
    "CompileOnBuild": true,
    "CompileOnSave": true,
    "EnableChainCompilation": true,
    "GenerateSourceMaps": true,
    "MinifyInPlace": false,
    **"OutputDirectory": 'OUTPUT FOLDER',**
    "ShowPreviewPane": true
  },
```